# Is it possible to get user to input using Scanner, then setting the character input as a String to do extra coding?

Tags: java, string, input

I am just starting out on Java, and have tried to use Scanner to set to allow a user to input characters, eg "Hello", but then to be able to use this input in a String to allow for further programming. Have currently the following:

```
System.out.print("Please enter a uncoded string: ");
String first = in.next();
String first = first.toUpperCase();
System.out.println("The decoded string is: "first );
```

However, I need to be able to say, for example, if the first letter of the string is "i", then the output will be changed to Upper Case using "toUpperCase".

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if statement to check if first letter of the input string is 'i':

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a uncoded string: ");
        String first = sc.nextLine();
        if (first.charAt(0) == 'i') {
            first = first.toUpperCase();
        }
        System.out.println("The decoded string is: " + first );
    }
```